# What is a quick way to estimate the haircut on a collateral that is actively traded

Tags: bond, collateral, securitization

If I have an traded asset like a bond with face value of 1 million, but currently trading at 0.9 million, can I simply say that the haircut, if I use this asset as a collateral for repo, is 1 - 0.9=0.1.
Or is it more involved than that?

Comment: The haircut is not related to the nominal. A bond trading at $90 might have a haircut of 0% 3% or 10% etc related to the quality of its collateral and market volatility, this simply means how much more you need to post to cover the monetary liability.